# Separate strings in row

Tags: string, r, cpu-word

I have data with id and last name

```
id             nameL              L1        L2
000005            ALRAMMAL        ALML
000006 BUSTAMANTE MARTINEZ        BUTE      MAEZ
000007        MENDEZ-PEREZ        MEEZ      PEEZ
000008               BOYCE        BOCE
000009               LAW          LAW
```

I like to separate the name into 2 part(if possible), and abstract the first 2 and last 2 letters from the separated name, and combine them together (like L1 and L2).
Thanks.

Comment: That's nice. Good luck with that.

Comment: Read help(substr), help(paste), help(split) and install the stringr package, play with them, and then get back to us.

Comment: I first tried to count the words in the string: ss$m = apply(ss[2],1, function(x) length(str_match_all( x, "\\S+" ))[1] ) but not working

Comment: This question is very specific and solvable by programming. It is only  maybe too complicated for a beginner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is pretty much in Spacedman's comment. `strsplit` and `substr` are key, and `nchar` will help you figure out how to get the last two characters.

#### split the strings up

```
x <- strsplit(mydf$nameL, " |-")
Lx <- vapply(x, length, 1L)
```

#### extract and paste together first and last two characters

```
Z <- unlist(lapply(x, function(y) {
  ifelse(nchar(y) <= 4, y,
         paste0(substr(y, 1, 2), substr(y, nchar(y)-1, nchar(y))))
}))
```

#### create a long `data.frame` with the new information

```
df <- data.frame(id = rep(mydf$id, Lx), 
                 L = Z, 
                 time = paste0("L", sequence(Lx)))
```

#### use `dcast` from "reshape2" to get the wider form of the data you want

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(df, id ~ time, value.var="L", fun.aggregate=as.character, fill = "")
#   id   L1   L2
# 1  5 ALAL     
# 2  6 BUTE MAEZ
# 3  7 MEEZ PEEZ
# 4  8 BOCE     
# 5  9  LAW
```